# How convert string to json or map to pair in dart if not valid json

Tags: json, dart

What is the best method to convert string to json in my example or map key value.

```
var str = "created_at: 2020-07-09T06:32:19Z, entry_id: 9510, field1: null, field2: 19.00"
json.decode(str);
```

Error:

```
FormatException: SyntaxError: Unexpected token c in JSON at position 0
```

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Stackoverflow. Seems like your string is not a valid JSON input. Please have a look at the [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON) or other websites and understand what the structure of JSON should look like.

Answer (score 1):

To convert Map/String -> JSON we use **json.encode()**

```
String str = "This is a String";
//for JSON format
json.encode(str);

Map<string,int> myMap = {"a":1};
//to convert into JSON
json.encode(myMap); // => "{"a":1}" JSON form
```

Similarly to convert JSON -> Map/String we use **json.decode()**

Answer (score 0):

While `json.decode` is the correct method to use, your string is not valid JSON. Your string in valid json would look something like this:

```js
{
  "created_at": "2020-07-09T06:32:19Z",
  "entry_id": 9510,
  "field1": null,
  "field2": 19.0
}
```

If you have a Map that you want to encode to JSON, use `json.encode`.

If this is your first time working with JSON, you might want to check out a tutorial on the syntax first (maybe [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iiADhChRriM))